# HDMI audio output not working in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, sound, pulseaudio, hdmi

I am having issues with the audio output while running **Ubuntu 16.04 LTS** on my HP Omen laptop.

I had to install the latest **Nvidia** driver for the **HDMI** video output to work but still there is no sound. I have looked through *Pulse* and tried to modify the configuration to **HDMI**, however all outputs say that they are unplugged. It also does not come up in the Sound Settings and when I list devices in the terminal ,it says that **HDMI** output is not available. I am also unable to see **Bluetooth** audio devices in *Pulse* when they're connected (unsure if this is related).

How do I resolve this issue ?

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1377653

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP has not signed on to in almost 2 years. It's impossible to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit the sound setting and make audio out to hdmi. 
Other wise sound will be from either ubuntu machine or ubuntu machine and hdmi both together.

Follow this blog, it should work.
I am looking for some automated solution too. Will update when found a better solution.

[Fix No Sound Through HDMI In External Monitor In Ubuntu Linux](https://itsfoss.com/how-to-fix-no-sound-through-hdmi-in-external-monitor-in-ubuntu/)

Answer (score 0):

I have yet to find a permanent solution offered that worked with my setup, but I have a similar issue in Win10 sometimes, and it seems that Sleep/ctrl-f1 and back will somehow "wake up" the HDMI audio.  It's slightly annoying, but works for some, like me.